# AJAX form submission doesn't work properly

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have a PHP form  that submits through AJAX through advancedSearch.php.

AJAX is working but when I submit the form, the browser just redirects me to advancedSearch.php instead of the form DIV in the HTML updating through AJAX.

Here is the code:
 
**HTML**

```
<form class="search"  action="advancedSearch.php" onSubmit="advancedSearch();return false;" method="post">
 ...

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
function advancedSearch() {

   var phone=document.getElementByName("phone")[0].value;
   console.log(phone);
   var criteria=document.getElementByName("criteria")[0].value;
   var age=document.getElementByName("age")[0].value;
   var city=document.getElementByName("city")[0].value;
   var data = 'phone=' + phone
        + '&criteria=' +criteria
    + '&age=' +age
         + '&city=' +city;

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  /*xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("list").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }*/

     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","advancedSearch.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send(data);

}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should post the relavent code in this question, not just a link

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: I checked the console and there are no errors...

Comment: Try to remove the `action="advancedSearch.php"` part of the html and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Now the submit button it's not doing anything...

Comment: Not doing anything like in; not sending the ajax request? There any console output this time?

Comment: Yes, it's not sending the request and still no output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add `id` to your form element and also use `e.preventDefault();`

**I am posting only example send values according you**

```
<form class="search"  action="advancedSearch.php" onSubmit="advancedSearch(event);" method="post">                                                                    
               <div id="phone">                                                                
                <label class="camp">Phone:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="phone" size="23" id="phone"><br>
                </div><br>

                <div id="age">
                <label class="camp">Age:</label><br>
                <select name="criteria" id="criteria">
                        <option value="">Choose...</option>
                        <option value="0">Grater than...</option>
                        <option value="1">Smaller than...</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="age" size="3" id="age"/><br>
                </div><br>

                <div id="city">
                <label class="camp">City:</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="city" size="23" id="city"><br>
                </div><br>

                <div id="searchButton">
                <input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search"/>
                </div>
        </form>
<script>
function advancedSearch(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var phone=document.getElementById("phone").value;
   var criteria= document.getElementById("criteria").value;
   var age= document.getElementById("age").value;
   var city= document.getElementById("city").value;
   var data = 'phone=' + phone
        + '&criteria=' +criteria
    + '&age=' +age
         + '&city=' +city;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      exit;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","advancedSearch.php",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send(data);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I changed document.getElementByName with document.getElementById and it worked...Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3720625 Must ask: are you sure that the console showed no error? Cause if this was the issue, the console should show error on trying to get `value` from a `element` that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add:

`event.preventDefault();`

to the form submission event listener function, to prevent the default form submission behaviour from happening.

Comment: He has "return false;" that also work but only if js goes to the return. I think that he has js error.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent page redirection, jQuery provides a function :

[`e.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

This is how to use :

Assuming you have code like this:

```
<form class="search"  action="advancedSearch.php" method="post">

<input type="submit" name="searchButton" onSubmit="advancedSearch();return false;" value="Search"/>
</form>
function advancedSearch(e)
{
         //here your javascript code.
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Does not look like OP uses the `jQuery` library.

Comment: You should add `return false;` before closing curly brace in `advancedSearch` function.

Comment: I've tried this, but it's still redirects me to advancedSearch.php.

Comment: @jite , @user3214779 `event.preventDefault()` is not jQuery method.

Comment: @KrisGeorgiev You are right, (I actually thought it was, so thanks for letting me know) but the answer starts with: `To prevent page redirection, jQuery provides a function :`. So my comment still applies to the specific answer. :P

Comment: @Jite jQuery provides e.preventDefault(). check jQuery doc [link](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: @user3214779, but the OP does not seem to use the `jQuery` library, so a `jQuery` function does not help. (We are starting to go around in circles now! hehe).